# How to enable dragging off the control to scroll and extend the selection

Tags: javascript, canvas, scroll, mouseevent, selection

I'm creating a custom scrolling control using HTML's Canvas that behaves a little like a spreadsheet grid. I have most standard cursor control behaviors set up, including using the mouse or arrow keys to extend the selection.

What I'd like to do next is allow the user to extend the selection by clicking and dragging off the canvas. I don't need help with the actual code, but I'd like to know if anyone has programmed something like this before, and if so, how did they approach it? Here are the ways I can think of:

- Track the mouse's general direction while over the control, and on mouseLeave+mouseDown set up a timer to scroll that direction until mouseEnter+mouseDown
- Determine the last location of the mouse before mouseLeave+mouseDown and use that to determine scroll direction
- Start a slow scroll when mouse is within a few pixels of an edge (which edge determines direction) and then scroll faster on mouseLeave+mouseDown
- Somehow involve window.mouseMove (instead of canvas.mouseMove) and track it that way (which seems really ugly to me)
- Something else I'm missing that will seem really obvious in retrospect

I can handle the code, I just want to figure out the best conceptual approach to take. Ideally, I'd love to handle extending the selection diagonally (scrolling right and down simultaneously, or at least alternating between the two so it appears that way), but that's not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.setCapture` to let your canvas continue to get mouse events even when the mouse is moved outside the canvas:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setCapture

Comment: Oh, wow... I was expecting to have to work a lot harder than this. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, coming back to this after messing with it, it looks like .setCapture is available only in IE and Firefox.

Comment: Here's an article that shows the workaround for cross-browser compatibility:  http://news.qooxdoo.org/mouse-capturing